# GuzzleHttp error after redirect

Tags: php, getstream-io

We have subscribe button on our page, when user is not authorised it shows popup auth form, after successful log in user gets redirected back to page and subscribes other users feed.

my code looks like this

```
$feed_which_follows = $this->getFeed($this>_main_feed_names['user'],$who_follows);
$res =  $feed_which_follows->followFeed($this->_main_feed_names['video'],$feed_to_follow);
```

But after `followFeed` is called, i get this error:

```
Argument 3 passed to GuzzleHttp\Client::request() must be of the type array, string given, called in ContentStream/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php on line 88 and defined
```

The strange this is that, if user is authorised and there is no need to redirect user back to page, everything works great. As soon as there is redirect involved, we get this error.

Comment: what version of GuzzleHttp are you using? did you install stream client with Composer?

Comment: i installed stream with composer, latest version. GuzzleHttp version is 6.0.2

Comment: what is the exact version number you got of stream-php?

Comment: 2.2.2 my composer.json looks like this : 
`{
  "require": {
    "get-stream/stream": "2.2.2"
  }
}`

Comment: fixed it. was caused by other library which used guzzle old version :| Thanks for support  Tommaso